# Creating Nested For-Loop on Google Sheets Script Editor to Auto-Extract Data into Required Format

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-sheets

I am trying to come up with a function that could extract data from one workbook to another that has a separate format. I will refer to the workbooks as "Source" and "Destination". So, on the "Source", I have the data arranged in yearly tabs. However, on "Destination", I have tabs indicating the regions. I have attached snapshots of the two workbooks.

Since I have no basics in programming, I tried to come up with a code but it didn't quite work. The following is my attempt at a nested for-loop which first extracts the data from the "2015" tab of the first region ("Ampang"), and pastes it into the other workbook in the "Ampang" tab and the "2015" row. I ran the debugging function and it says that the "var data" is undefined.

```
function D() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//open destination worksheet
  var sss = ss.getSheets(); //get all destination sheets


  //var sheetname = ss.getSheetName(); //get sheet names
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jJ8QysQTmS5tG4wvNCxqdbWvAbdbmJm5uatdgIHe6tw/edit#gid=793399042"); //open where data is located
  var sheet = sheet1.getSheets(); //get all the sheets required


  for (j = 0; j<sss.length; j++) {
  for (i = 0; i <sheet.length; i++) {
    switch(sheet[i].getSheetName()) {
      case "Main Menu" :
      break;
      default:
      var data = sheet.getSheets()[i].getRange(i+1, i+2, 1, 2); //get the data for Specific Region and then Changing the Year
      var destination = sss[j].getRange(j,j+1,1,2); //pasting the data to the specific year at the Specific Region Tab/
      data.copyTo(destination); 

    }
  }
```

}
}

**[Update 1]**
So, I realized that the copyTo() function doesn't work when the data are in separate workbooks so I have come up with a new code below:

```
function D() {
  // define the source sheets
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jJ8QysQTmS5tG4wvNCxqdbWvAbdbmJm5uatdgIHe6tw/edit#gid=793399042");

  // get all source sheets
  var source = ss.getSheets();

  // define the target sheets
  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get all target sheets
  var target = ts.getSheets();

  // set nested for-loop
  for (j = 0; j < target.length; j++) { 
  for (i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    if (source[i].getSheetName() !== "Main Menu") {
    var rangeSource = source[i].getRange(i+1,i+1,1,2); // get the source range
      var values = rangeSource[i].getValues(); // get the values from the set range
    } 
    if (target[j].getSheetName() !== "Main Menu") {
      var rangeTarget = target[j].getRange(j+1,j+1,1,2); //get the target range
      rangeTarget.setValues(values[i]); // paste the values to the target range
    }
  }
  }
}
```

However, the var rangeSource and values are currently undefined. I still am trying to find the source of the error.

[Source Sheets Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrgH9.jpg)

[Destination Sheets Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URKH2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `sheet` as all the sheets

```
  var sheet = sheet1.getSheets(); //get all the sheets required
```

So `data` needs to be

```
  var data = sheet[i].getRange(i+1, i+2, 1, 2); //get the data for Specific Region and then Changing the Year
```

See is that helps.

Comment: I changed that and the line works now but I came to realize that copyTo() only works when the data is in the same worksheet. So, I changed the code but I am having problems with var rangeSource and values because it is undefined right now. I am stump as to why the for loop is not working there. Please check the edit to my original post for the updated code thank you

Comment: Try `var values = rangeSource.getValues();`

Comment: So, I ran the Debug function and I can see the values that need to be extracted. However, I am stuck at the error saying "Cannot convert Array to number[][]"

var values is an array of ["715, 687500"] - the two values i wanted to extract

but

var rangeTarget is an object. 

Did I use the wrong function?

Comment: Ah that is because it should be `rangeTarget.setValues(values)` and not `rangeTarget.setValues(values[i])`